# MapStruct ignore automatically unmapped properties

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct with big models (more than 50 fields) shared between different business use cases in my code. Depending on the entry point, some properties will be mapped and some not. When I build my project, I will always get the "WARNING: Unmapped target properties" message.

I have researched and seen that it is possible to tell the mapstruct to ignore the field by using the semantic

```
@Mapping(target = "propName", ignore = true)
```

The problem is, given my objects with so many fields, it would take a lot of code to ignore each single property in each mapper class. I also do not want this Warning on my log. Is there any way to tell mapstruct to ignore what is not mapped, avoiding this message?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can set the "unmapped target policy" on the `@Mapper` level or via `@MapperConfig` to share a setting across several mappers:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface MyMapper {}
```

Comment: is there something to do the same at method level ?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct-ignore-unmapped-properties

Answer (score 19):

For ignore automapping
MapStruct 1.3.0.Final Reference Guide:

> By means of the @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true) the default
>   behavior will be explicit mapping, meaning that all mappings have to
>   be specified by means of the @Mapping and no warnings will be issued
>   on missing target properties.

```
@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
OneObj map(TwoObj two);
```

Comment: It would be nice if this can be configured on a global level and not just between two types.