# How to map JAXB elements annotated with @XMLSeeAlso using mapStruct?

Tags: java, jaxb, mapstruct, object-object-mapping

I'm trying to map a bean which has some JAXB elements like @XmlSeeAlso, @XmlElement, @XmlSchemaType as properties for that class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Customer")
@XmlSeeAlso({PersonalCustomer.class, BusinessCustomer.class})
public class Customer extends Role {

 @XmlElement(name = "AMLLineOfBusiness")
private LOB amlLineOfBusiness;
 // 50 odd properties
 //some properties with XmlElement/XmlSchemaType 
 // getters and setters   
}

@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {
     PersonalCustomer personcalCustomerToPersonalCustomer(PersonalCustomer pc);
@Mappings({
    /*Several other ignore mappings*/
    @Mapping(target="AMLLineOfBusiness",ignore=true)
    })
     Customer customerToCustomer(Customer customer);
   }
```

Now I'm facing below issues when mapping using mapStruct.

1. The bean PersonalCustomer is not being mapped. I don't see it in the 
   response. But it works perfectly when using dozer. All I need to do is 
   define it in it's mapping in dozer config xml. I tried similar thing in 
   mapStruct. I defined personcalCustomerToPersonalCustomermethod in mapper 
   interface with required mappings and ignoring not required fields. Although 
   implementation is there in the mapperImpl but I don't see it being used 
   anywhere in the impl class.
2. While ignoring the fields which have either @XmlElement or @XmlSchemaType, 
   I'm getting compilation error while generating impl code. Below is the error 
   statck trace. I got compilation error when I used amlLineOfBusiness.

   [70,2] error: Unknown property "amlLineOfBusiness" in result type com.role.Customer. Did you mean "lineOfBusiness"?
   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on
    project service-jar: Compilation failure
   C:\Perforce\service-jar\2018.08.0\service-jar\src\main\java\com\mapstruct\mapper\CustomerMapper.java:[70,2] error: Unknown property "amlLineOfBusiness" in result type com.role.Customer. Did you mean "lineOfBusiness"?
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:188)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:184)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure

   The above is resolved when I used the name value of 
   (@XmlElement(name="AMLLineOfBusiness")) annotation to ignore. I couldn't 
    understand what exactly going on here.
3. By default mapStruct is mapping fields of super class too. In my case, 
   Customer class also getting properties of Role. There is no other option 
   except using ignore=true on each property. This is kind of hectic as I'm 
   having 50 odd fields and tens of similar mappers based on service 
   requirement. I wish mapStruct had feature to ignore all fields by default or 
   a strategy to map only specified fields.

Note that both source and destination types are same here. I only need to map certain fields depending on the requirement. I'm stuck here. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you share the `@Mapping` where you use `amlLineOfBusiness`?

Comment: @Filip. Edited the question. It is present in Customer class. I doesn't need to be mapped for current service. So added ignore tag for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have 3 different problems.

1. It seems what you are trying to achieve is for MapStruct to detect all possible implementations for `Customer` (or see `@XmlSeeAlso`) and use the method you need. This is not possible automatically in MapStruct. See  [#131](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131) for an existing feature request.
2. This should happen when you have not defined the property correct. MapStruct actually looks into the getters and setters only (not in the field). So if you getter is `getAM` then your `@Mapping(target = "AMLLineOfBusiness", ignore = true)`
3. This is similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527537/how-to-map-only-specified-fields-using-mapstruct) question. Maybe you can try [Reusing mapping configurations](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_reusing_mapping_configurations)

A possible solution for 1 would be you to an instance of on your side.

```
@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {
    PersonalCustomer personcalCustomerToPersonalCustomer(PersonalCustomer pc);

    default Customer customerToCustomer(Customer customer) {
        if (customer instanceOf PersonalCustomer) {
            return personalCustomerToPersonalCustomer((PersonalCustomer) pc);
        } else if (customer instanceOf BusinessCustomer) {
            return businessCustomerToBusinessCustomer((BusinessCustomer) pc);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for such things is that MapStruct is an annotation processor so it generated code during compilation time. On the other side Dozer is working with runtime information. Dozer can get the class during runtime and pick the right method. MapStruct cannot deduce all the possible implementations.

Comment: First one is my main problem. I'm totally stuck there. It is actually creating an implementation for personcalCustomerToPersonalCustomer(..) in generated impl code. But I don't see that method implementation being used anywhere in customerToCustomer(). So obviously mapping is not being done in the resulting bean.

Comment: See my edited answer. I now understand what exactly you need. In any case it has nothing to do with `@XmlSeeAlso`

Comment: Here PersonalCustomer and BusinessCustomer extends Custome class. Each has seperate fields. Now when I above solution, though it is mapping the fields of specified PersonalCustomer and BusinessCustomer but it's not mapping fields of Customer class.

Comment: That is strange, as MapStruct looks in the entire hiearchy to perform the mapping. Can you provide an example and if it really isn't working create an issue

Comment: A little hack solved the issue. It is appearing when I use this way along with shared configuration. It can wait for now.